# Plugin to add several video clips with cross fades between them all?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a plugin or an automated way to add a whole directory of videos and have a cross fade added between each of them in Blender?

Comment: I am not aware of one. But I have needed an excuse to make a script for a while.. let me see how hard this is going to be!

Comment: I can do it! Are there any specific options you need?

Comment: @Zachman it would be good if the timings could be edited. Of course anything you can do would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay! Also, how would you like it to order the files. In the order they are in the folder, or by alphabetical/number.

Comment: Could they be imported through Blender's native file-opening dialog? That supports sorting by name, extension, date, or size.

Comment: There is a slideshow plugin [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360518-Addon-Dynamic-Slideshow) which may help you get started. It does almost what I need but with multiple cameras in one scene, not with a directory of videos.

Comment: I have the basic functionality down, I just need to make a UI Panel and allow the user to choose the directory!

Comment: Thank you so much! When you're finished be sure to answer this with a link to the script so I can mark yours correct.

Comment: No problem! It has been fun! Where would you like the panel to go?

Comment: I don't know what it's called, but I think the panel on the left with vertical tabs will do. It could be added as an additional tab.

Comment: The Toolshelf it is!

Comment: So I have most everything done. I still have a few options to add, and it only works with .mov and .mp4 files so far. I also still have to add the sorting ability.

Here it is for testing: https://github.com/MrSprite/VSEC

Comment: Consider marking the Script down below as answered as it seems to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I have finished the script. The script can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/MrSprite/VSEC

I have not added sorting by file size or date yet, but all other features should be there!
Let me know if it works!

Comment: It might be better to add the panel to the sequencer: `bl_space_type='SEQUENCE_EDITOR'` `bl_region_type = 'UI'` :)

Comment: Updated the sctipt! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Make sure to accept this answer so others can get help if they have the same question!

Comment: Consider copying a current version of your script into the Answer in case of expiring pages or links...