# Extract sequence of frames from imported MP4 - scripted?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, video

I would like to extract a sequence of images files from an imported mp4, ideally using a script. I'll then analyze the images with python to start extracting cues and other information, so they don't necessarily need to be absolute best possible quality.

For example:

```
frame_numbers = range(15*60*24, 30*60*24, 96)
```

returns 225 frame numbers between 15:00 and 30:00 at 24fps.

Can this be scripted?

If not, what is the quickest way to do this manually? (ouch!)

Comment: You're in the material node editor, click on the next icon for the compositor: http://www.blender.org/manual/fr/composite_nodes/introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the compositor.

All you need is to prepare a simple node setup where you have a `Movie Clip` (Input) Node connected to the `Composite` (Output) Node. Load your video into the movie clip node, set a few small params in the script below (namely the output folder where you'd like to save the extracted frames and the frame range), and run the script.

[image: Node Setup]

The script will copy the video dimensions and set up your render settings accordingly (but will not alter the output file format).

```
import bpy
from os.path import join

S = bpy.context.scene
n = S.node_tree

vidNode = n.nodes['Movie Clip']

# Set Render Settings dimensions according to video
S.render.resolution_percentage = 100
S.render.resolution_y          = vidNode.clip.size[1]
S.render.resolution_x          = vidNode.clip.size[0]

# Render desired frame numbers ( UPDATE THESE AS NEEDED )
start = 5
end   = 200
step  = 3
frame_numbers = range(start, end, step)

outputFolder = "C:/tmp/test"    # <=== Update this 
for f in frame_numbers:
    S.frame_set( f )
    fileName = str(f) + S.render.file_extension
    S.render.filepath = join( outputFolder, fileName )
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still = True )
```

Copy this to a new text file in the text editor, change the values in the `outputFolder` variable and the `start`, `end` and `step` for generating frame_numbers, and press "Run Script".

If you'd like, you can also automate the creation of the node setup and load the video to the movie clip node; there are [several nice answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python) here in StackExchange showing how to create and manipulate nodes via python.

Comment: Sweet! I'll try it out in a few hours. I'm curious - does "movie clip" mean it is assumed to be short? My mp4 file is 500MB and about 1 hour long. (nice rug btw)

Comment: Movie clip is the term dedicated to any video files (as opposed to image sequences, the other, perhaps more common node for manipulating a sequence of frames).

Comment: No problem, glad it works :)

Comment: @uhoh - the `dimensions` prop was the wrong one. I fixed the script to read from the Movie Clip Node's `clip.size` property, which provides the right dimensions, and even doesn't require flipping x and y :)

Comment: Yipeee!! It virtually works right out of the box! Thanks again @TLousky for an excellent and complete answer. I'm a happy camper.