# Extract audio to file from movie clip - with Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

In [this excellent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43531/5334) I learned how to extract a series of individual frames from a movie clip node.

This solution suits me well - there is a python script, and a few nodes, and it runs automatically.

Is there a way I could extract the audio from a clip - either the whole thing, or possibly just between two frame number limits, using a similarly simple technique in Blender? For me simple is python and nodes - I am not an advanced user, and something I can automate and customize is the most useful in my case.

I've have tried to examine the attributes of the `vidNode` but didn't find anything that looked like audio:

```
S = bpy.context.scene
n = S.node_tree

vidNode = n.nodes['Movie Clip']
```

[image]

Comment: What about ffmpeg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27413824/3091066 ?

Comment: @poor Thanks! I'm sure there are several ways to do this, but I am looking for something that runs in a python environment - preferably either my anaconda installation or preferably in Blender. The more ways I learn to use capabilities of Blender, the more I can learn about Blender. If there is a way I can do this using Blender, I would like to understand how. Even if it's not the "best" way to do it, if it can be done here I'd really like to do it here.

Comment: In my opinion your best bet is to use VSE. Even if I don't know its python capabilities I think it's the only part of Blender that can do audio things (except Game Engine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there isn't a node with that capability built in. The simplest that you might script is the following:

- add the clip to the VSE
- set start and endframe: `bpy.context.scene.frame_start`  and `.frame_end`
- call the mixdown operator: `bpy.ops.sound.mixdown` ([see the docs for parameters](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.sound.html?highlight=bpy.ops.sound.mixdown#bpy.ops.sound.mixdown))
- reset frame start/end if you need to.

something like this.

```
import bpy

def main(filepath_source, filepath_destination, frame_start=0, frame_end=20):
    scn = bpy.context.scene

    scn.frame_start = frame_start
    scn.frame_end = frame_end

    if not scn.sequence_editor:
        scn.sequence_editor_create()

    sequences = scn.sequence_editor.sequences
    sequences.new_sound(
        name='drone_detroit', 
        filepath=filepath_source,
        channel=0, frame_start=0
    )
    bpy.ops.sound.mixdown(filepath=filepath_destination)   

fp_source = r"C:\Users\zeffi\Downloads\DRONE\0001-2964.avi"
fp_destination = r"C:\Users\zeffi\OneDrive\Documents\chopper_drone4.flac"

main(fp_source, fp_destination, frame_start=500, frame_end=560)
```

the `sequences.new_sound`, lifts the audio track off the `.avi`.

The mixdown operator will output the audio of whatever is between those two frames.

Comment: zeffii to the rescue - OK that's great. This will drag me kicking and screaming into the world of the video sequence editor - which is a good thing. There's a typhoon coming so I'll be stuck indoors in need of a project, perfect timing!