# How to add sound to sequencer using python

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I want to add music via python.
I tried:

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add(bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add(filepath="//mymusic.mp3", frame_start=0, channel=1)
```

but somehow it gives me the error:

```
drop file blabla
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blabla", line 60, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add  In this case you need to be in the 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR' space.

Comment: since i dont really want to go there and just add the sound is there no workaround? or can i switch to the editor space with python and then back?

Comment: `scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name, filepath, channel, frame_start)`

Comment: NameError: name 'scene' is not defined

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62163/extract-audio-to-file-from-movie-clip-with-blender/62858#62858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

scene = context.scene 

if not scene.sequence_editor:
    scene.sequence_editor_create()

#Sequences.new_sound(name, filepath, channel, frame_start)    
soundstrip = scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound("toad", "~/toad_sound.mp3", 3, 1)
```