# Running Blender Script via Console - Error

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, command-line

I wrote a Blender Script to create me images and Text elements (via Python Script) in a Timeline. All Works! But via Console it doesn't Work.
I know, it has something to do with the GUI and the context objects i used: But how i should change this?

**Error when i try running command Line** `blender -b C:\Users\xxxxx\test.blend --background -P C:\Users\xxxxx\timeline.py`

[image]

```
 bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(type='TEXT', frame_start=frame_start, frame_end=frame_end, channel=10)
    obj1=bpy.ops.transform.seq_slide(value=(-6, 5), orient_axis_ortho='X', snap=False, view2d_edge_pan=True)
    
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sequence_editor.sequences_all['Text'].text=text1
    textKey='Text'
    count=-1
```

**Working Example if i execute my Python Code in Blender (GUI)**
[image]

Comment: There is probably something missing in the context object (the *context.scene.sequence_editor*?). Here is a similar question  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63834/107598 with an accepted answer.

Comment: ok, found a solution:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/importing-multiple-movie-clips-inside-one-directory-via-script