# Setting up Tracking Stabilization via Python API

Tags: scripting, video, tracking

I have a project that uses the (Intel) RealSense camera and I am capturing a short set of frames that feature a single face. The camera SDK provides me with a good way to do landmark recognition in image space. So I can tell where the nose/mouth and other features are located.

I have some strict constraints on what I want the final set of frames to be stabilized like. And have been able to meet those constraints by using the video stabilization system manually in Blender. Unfortunately I need to process quite a few of these, and manual editing is out of the question.

My question is: **Is there a  way for me to programmatically supply the initial tracking points for the stabilization system, and have it process the whole video using those initial points.**

For example: *I provide ears and nose (x & y image space coordinates), as the points to track in the first frame. And Blender uses them to track + stabilize the rest of the frames.*

Thanks for any advice, and please tell me if you need more detail for this question.

Comment: You could provide a sample scene with two "dummy" markers and then just use python to place them at the correct locations and start the tracking process. Maybe some of my [automation of the VSE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41747/2843) helps for some points regarding Blenders python automation...