# Change Encoding Settings through Python API

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, video, encoding

I need help with the python api for setting the video encoding in Blender 2.79a.

I have already set the output type to `FFMPEG` via:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = 'FFMPEG'
```

I now need to set the encoding to output video in MP4 format and haven't been able to find this information yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set [`Output.file_format`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=file_format#bpy.types.Image.file_format) to `FFMPG` and adjust the attributes of [`Render.ffmpeg`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings):

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
rd = scene.render

# Set output type
rd.image_settings.file_format = "FFMPEG"

# Set output format
rd.ffmpeg.format = "MPEG4"

# Set the codec
rd.ffmpeg.codec = "H264"

...
```

Other options:

- [`codec`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.codec): `MPEG1, MPEG2, MPEG4, HUFFYUV, DV, H264, THEORA, DNXHD, PNG`
- [`format`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.format): `MPEG1, MPEG2, MPEG4, AVI, QUICKTIME, DV, H264, XVID, OGG, MKV`
- [`video_bitrate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.video_bitrate): `0 - infinity` *(integer)*
- [`maxrate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.maxrate): `0 - infinity` *(integer)*
- [`audio_channels`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.audio_channels): `MONO, STEREO, SURROUND4, SURROUND51, SURROUND71`
- [`audio_bitrate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.audio_bitrate): `32 - 384`

For **all available options**, see the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#module-bpy.types) on [`FFmpegSettings`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FFmpegSettings.html#module-bpy.types).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the solution in this 
[post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36928/generate-video-sequencer-project-from-a-script/41747#41747)

To set the individual settings for ffmpeg use:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.ffmpeg.<SETTING_TO_MODIFY>
```

For example to set settings to use H264 with MP4 container:

```
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.ffmpeg.format = "MPEG4"
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.ffmpeg.codec = "H264"
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.ffmpeg.constant_rate_factor = "MEDIUM"
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.ffmpeg.ffmpeg_preset = "MEDIUM"
```