# How do I add a new preset to the FFMPEG Presets list in Blender?

Tags: encoding

I have done a lot of customization in the encoding settings. I want to add these settings to FFMPEG Presets to quickly access them later. How can I do that? I want to add a new preset to the list that appears in the picture I added.

[image: FFMPEG Presets list in Blender]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presets are python script files. They can be found in the folder for the program.

*version number*/scripts/presets/ffmpeg.

[image]

Create your own and save them there, they will show up next time you open blender. To understand the options, use the existing ones as reference.

[image]

Read: [Change Encoding Settings through Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106659/change-encoding-settings-through-python-api)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.